# Create custom signature appearance with iText7

Tags: pdf, itext7

I want to use my custom signature appearance using iText7. Currently in iText there are predefined signature appearance designs.

```
signatureAppearance.SetRenderingMode(PdfSignatureAppearance.RenderingMode.GRAPHIC_AND_DESCRIPTION);
```

Could someone help me regarding this.
Thanks in advance.
Regards

Comment: how do you want it to look like?

Comment: a potentially relevant answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/35485026/1566339

Answer (score 0):

As you already found out,

> in iText there are predefined signature appearance designs.

But you also have the option to design the appearance completely yourself, simply retrieve the `Layer2` form XObject:

```
PdfFormXObject layer2XObject = signatureAppearance.GetLayer2();
```

To this XObject you can add arbitrary contents which will become the visualization of the signature.

---

The term "layer 2" refers to the way iText builds the signature appearance. It emulates the way Adobe Acrobat does this. This way used to allow changing appearances reflecting the validation status of the signature, a feature deprecated meanwhile for more than a decade. It also allows to add a signature field background (in "layer 0") during field creation which remains during actual signing which according to this scheme leaves layer 0 as is.

As a signature appearance only contains these layers by convention (following Adobe's lead) and not by specification, you should neither count on signature fields you retrieve to be structured like that nor expect PDF processors processing your PDFs further to respect them.

Comment: I want to make following type of signature style using iText7.

https://www.dropbox.com/scl/fi/yoprn2m6044m697ltmc89/Custom-Signature-Appearance.paper?dl=0&rlkey=51cui4ic28oc4et238y1e9xff

Comment: How far have you gotten creating content of that style in the `PdfFormXObject layer2XObject`?

Comment: In your code you don't add anything to `layer2XObject`. Thus, it's empty.