# itext7: positioning the signature's rectangle

Tags: itext

Regarding the rectangle that is passed to the `PdfSignatureAppearance`, can someone tell me why the y seems to be growing from the bottom to the top of the page? For instance, a rectangle created wioth the (10, 10, 200, 50) is position near the bottom of the page and one created with the (10, 750, 200, 50) is placed near the top of the page.

One more question: when using the GRAPHIC_AND_DESCRIPTION mode, is there a way to place the image near the left side of the rectangle instead of placing it near the its right half?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> why the y seems to be growing from the bottom to the top of the page?

Because that's how coordinate systems in pdfs are specified. In contrast to many bitmap image APIs which have it the other way around, pdfs use coordinate systems as commonly known from math.

> when using the GRAPHIC_AND_DESCRIPTION mode, is there a way to place the image near the left side of the rectangle instead of placing it near the its right half?

The modes offered by itext use a rigid layout. But an alternative is to design the whole appearance yourself! See numerous other questions here, for example [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65635095/1729265), [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59068600/1729265), or [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57868289/1729265).

Comment: Thanks again :) Not sure on why I was really conviced that (0,0) was on the top...

Comment: Actually the default user space origin (0,0) of a PDF page can be anywhere, either on the page or outside the visible page area. Fairly often, though, it is the left bottom corner.