# How do I change the rectangle style and default field descriptions of a pdfsignature in iText?

Tags: java, pdf, itext

While doing deferred signing, I create this empty signature in my pdf

```
    public byte[] emptySignature(String src, String dest, String fieldname)
        throws IOException, GeneralSecurityException, DocumentException {

    PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(src);
    FileOutputStream os = new FileOutputStream(dest);
    PdfStamper stamper = PdfStamper.createSignature(reader, os, '\0');
    PdfSignatureAppearance appearance = stamper.getSignatureAppearance();

    appearance.setLocation("Office");
    appearance.setReason("For testing");

    Rectangle r = new Rectangle(36, 748, 244, 680);
    r.setBackgroundColor(BaseColor.WHITE);
    r.setBorderColor(BaseColor.RED);
    r.setBorder(1);
    r.setBorder(2);
    r.setBorder(3);
    r.setBorder(4);

    appearance.setVisibleSignature(r, 1, fieldname);

    ExternalSignatureContainer external = new ExternalBlankSignatureContainer(PdfName.ADOBE_PPKLITE, PdfName.ADBE_PKCS7_DETACHED);
    MakeSignature.signExternalContainer(appearance, external, 8192);

    byte[] data = IOUtils.toByteArray(appearance.getRangeStream());

    return data;
}
```

After signing my pdf has this stamp with default text like "Digitally signed by...Date:...Reason:...Location".

1. How do I change this text? Obviously I can modify Location with setLocation, but how can I change field descriptions and "Digitally signed" to something else?
2. Can I change the style of a signature rectangle? Trying to set border and background color to rectangle before doing setVisibleSignature doesn't work

I use itext 5.5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How do I change this text? Obviously I can modify Location with setLocation, but how can I change field descriptions and "Digitally signed" to something else?

You can design your completely own appearance of the signature, see for example [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45859595/1729265), [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49009766/1729265), [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35485026/1729265), and many others.

> Can I change the style of a signature rectangle? Trying to set border and background color to rectangle before doing setVisibleSignature doesn't work

Only the position and dimension of the rectangle you set using `appearance.setVisibleSignature` are used. For custom appearances see above.

Comment: Thank you, I ended up using SetLayer2Text method